# for all his wealth vs with all his wealth (concession and cause)

Tags: meaning, difference

Could both "for" and "with" used for concession and cause? Is there any difference in meaning between the pairs below? If not, which preposition is more usual in this context?

Concession (= despite)

- For all his wealth, he is humble.
- With all his wealth, he is humble.

Cause (= due to)

- For all his wealth, he has nothing to worry about.
- With all his wealth, he has nothing to worry about.

Comment: Idiomatically, ***for all [that]*** is the standard for "despite" contexts *(all that **notwithstanding**)*, whereas the "reason, cause" sense is normally expressed by ***with all that = given all that = since all that is true***. So the second of your first pair and the first of your second pair are non-idiomatic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would say more non sequitur than not idiomatic. "Because of all his wealth, he is humble"   is natural but nonsensical.

Comment: @Andrew: But we *can* use ***with*** in "despite" contexts. Take [*Have you not learned that **with** all your wealth you are nobody and I am somebody?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+all+your+wealth+you+are%22), where rather than say it's a  "non sequitur", we'd simply assume that ***with*** is semantically equivalent to ***even with***. That's to say there's a certain amount of flexibility with ***with***, but not with ***because***. So with your example (assuming it came from a native speaker), I'd have to suppose he's a pious man who's grateful for what he's been "given".

Comment: @FumbleFingers   I would argue that your example is an ellipsis for *"**even** with (all your wealth)"*, used, as you say, to mean "despite".   But I agree that this usage is not as narrow as "due to", as it's often found in negative constructions, e.g. *"You would think that, **with all his gifts**, he would be more successful (but he isn't)"*